# What's the meaning of "just as well" in this sentence and the sentence's meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

I saw this sentence on a book:

Not replying works just as well as "I don't know."

I don't understand what it means. Is there any way to analyze its grammar? 
I know the phrase "just as well", but I'm not sure if it's still the same meaning in this sentence.

---

After thinking more about it, a new thought occurred to me.

Maybe I should take "not replying" as a noun, "works" as the verb in the sentence, and this sentence means that "not replying" is just the same thing as "I don't know." Is that right?

Comment: You asked a question here in ELL. If I do not know the answer, I do not answer. I do not bother to say, "I don't know." For this specific site I'd say, "Not replying works better than "I don't know." In your example it  means a non reply suggests the person has no answer or does not know and it is unnecessary to say so. A non reply works the same way/as well as "I don't know."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *works just as well* in your quote means that two things work equally well. The two things are:

1. Not replying; and
2. the phrase "I don't know".

So your quote is saying that *someone who doesn't reply* has the same effect as someone who replies, "I don't know".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been thinking about this for almost an hour and new thought arrived all of a sudden. Appreciate your confirmation.

Comment: @user32250 You're welcome. :)